# Where do people go (online) to present big ideas they have discovered?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I can't realistically travel, but is there somewhere online where I can present some ideas? Or do I just put it on arXiv and hope someone important reads it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not a physics question.

Comment: You can write a paper and submit it to a journal for peer-review.

Comment: Post it here and let us evaluate

Comment: Don't post it here. We explicitly don't do personal theories. See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4539/7433 .

Comment: Let's put it this way, you can post your personal pet hypotheses here, but they will get a lot of down votes and your post will be closed very quickly. There are plenty of pay-to-publish journals that will publish almost any nonsense you can imagine, but nobody important will read it. The bigger problem you have with all of this is to come up with something that does not fall into the nonsense category, because that, you see, takes a lot of hard work.

Comment: Go here : http://vixra.org/

Answer (score 2):

No clue but you are not allowed to post stuff like this here.

I personally like physics and find it interesting and enjoy thinking on things but this place is for published ideas that has been accepted by a majority of the physics community

https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4539/7433.

Comment: He is in entirely the wrong place. We *do not* do personal theories here: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4539/7433.

Comment: Weird.  I personally like physics and find anything related to it interesting. C'est la vie  :/

Comment: I have seen online sites, that publish "non-standard" theories, perhaps you should start there. You can try arxiv too.

Comment: I think the Physics area of arxiv now requires sponsorship of some sort if you are an unknown in order to submit something for publication on the site.  An unknown is someone who does not have a record of publishing in peer reviewed journals, not on staff at some university, or something like that.  ArXiv does have a description of the requirements on-line, sorry I can't point to it as it has been quite a while since I read it.

Comment: If you have not been to undergrad or grad school in physics it is more than likely that your theory is not new or valid. Lots of reasons for that, but mainly it is where you learn physics. This is not the 18th century when the science was young enough that this was more plausible. Have you thought of going to university and maybe your theory would be much improved? Why not put in your time if you think you can really contribute? Even going to a university and talking to a faculty member may impress them, or let you see you are pretty far away from having rigorously thought through the theory.